# How to create a nodejs archetype from maven

Tags: eclipse, node.js, maven, maven-plugin, maven-eclipse-plugin

The current default nature of the project is '*org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature*' (Java nature) But I want change the default nature of the project to *org.nodeclipse.ui.NodeNature*' (nodejs).

Where should I specify this plugin in the maven archetype and in which phase .

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/provide-project-natures-and-build-commands.html

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>

                <projectnature>org.nodeclipse.ui.NodeNature</projectnature>
                <projectnature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</projectnature>
                <projectnature>tern.eclipse.ide.core.ternnature</projectnature>

                <buildcommand>com.eclipsesource.jshint.ui.builder</buildcommand>


            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Its not working for me .Any thoughts?.

Thanks

Comment: What "following plugin" do you mean?

Comment: I used 'maven-eclipse-plugin' in the pom.xml but that did not work .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to replace the Java Nature with the Node one. AFAICT, the page referenced gives instructions for **adding** natures to the default via the pom. The default is defined in the .project file... replace the 'buildspec' and 'natures' tags in that file with:

```
    <buildSpec>
            <buildCommand>
                    <name>com.eclipsesource.jshint.ui.builder</name>
                    <arguments>
                    </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
            <nature>org.nodeclipse.ui.NodeNature</nature>
            <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
            <nature>tern.eclipse.ide.core.ternnature</nature>
    </natures>
```

You may need to add a .jshintrc file to the root of the project as well, but iI think you can build that in the Preferences -> JSHint panel

Comment: Thanks  . But I am not looking to change the .project file manually, I want to set the nature of the project to nodejs at the time of project creation by using my archetype .